# Android Studio Backup Source to Repository

Tags: android, git, repository

Recently I stuck with too many Android projects old/new NOT backed up, except manually copy/paste to second hard drive.

As I am developing in C# too, in Visual Studio I connect to Microsoft small team(free) repository and commit changes so, I'am secure.

I tried Android Studio Git before, it's free it's working but it's public.
My apps are for business and cannot be public. 
GitHub has private from $7/month which is more than I paid for cloud hosting.
I am considering building my own repository. Any thoughts and idea maybe.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://bitbucket.org . It allows you to keep private repositories for free

Answer (score 2):

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) provides private repository for free*.